# Pass list of arguments to a command in shell

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments

If I have a list of files say `file1` ... `file20`, how to I run a command that has the list of files as the arguments, e.g. `myccommand file1 file2 ... file20`?

Comment: You have a list where? In an array variable? In a file? In your argument vector? Somewhere else?

Comment: Good question. I assumed @rhlee meant access the cmdline args, but maybe not.

Comment: A list of files in a directory, I created them using the `seq` command.

Comment: A list stored how? A list stored in a scalar variable? A list stored in a file? A list stored in an array? I still don't know what you mean by "list".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your list is in your argument vector -- that is to say, if you were started with:

```
./yourscript file1 file2 ...
```

then you'd run

```
mycommand "$@"
```

If your list is in an array:

```
mycommand "${my_list_of_files[@]}"
```

If your list is in a NUL-delimited file:

```
xargs -0 -- mycommand <file_with_argument_list
```

If your list is in a newline-delimited file (which you should never do for filenames, since filenames can legitimately contain newlines):

```
readarray -t filenames <file_with_argument_list
mycommand "${filenames[@]}"
```

If by "list", you just mean that you have a sequence of files:

```
mycommand file{1..20}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusion, by  "list" I meant sequence of files. `mycommand file{1..20}` worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Look into the `shift` bash command (`man bash`). You can iterate, taking `$1` each time.

```
for n in $(seq 1 $#); do
  echo $1
  shift
done
```

Call this file `myshift.sh`. Then

```
$ ./myshift.sh a b c 
a
b
c
```

Comment: `for` loops already have a standard way of iterating over command-line arguments. This is just a non-standard way of writing `for n; do echo "$n"; done`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're generating a list of files with `seq`, you can just use command substitution to drop them into the command line:

```
mycommand $(seq ...)
```

although that will fail if the filenames so generated have any spaces (or tabs or newlines...) in them.

You can also use bash's curly-brace expansion to generate them instead of `seq`, for instance `file{1..10}` to generate `file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 file8 file9 file10`.  This has the advantage of working even if the filename contains spaces in the common part, as long as you quote it properly (e.g. `"file name"{1..10}`).

Comment: Yep, the curly bracket expansion works. It's a shame I can't mark multiple answers as the "correct one".

Comment: Well, that part of my answer was redundant with the one you accepted anyway. The only reason I answered at all was because you had added a comment about `seq` that hadn't been addressed yet.  Not sure that's enough to leave this answer here..